# Parasite addition to tags during revision redaction

Tags: bug, tags, design, moderator-tools, revision-redaction

During the [redaction of post revision](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/222575/redact/78398322-9d1a-4a40-91bf-d17832fb926c) (link for staff) I'm faced with that a weird tag rendering:

> [image]

As you can see there are two vertical red lines on the right hand side of each tag. Possible culprits of this are given in the red notes earlier on the page:

> [image]

It's even more ugly in dark mode:

> [image]